# Nonnegative vs non-negative

Tags: terminology

When you write about integers that are not negative, do you write "non-negative integers" or "nonnegative integers" in papers in US English?

EDIT:

In https://ieeecs-media.computer.org/media/conferences/cpstemplates/8.5x11x2/instruct8.5x11x2.pdf we see

> The prefix “non” is not a word; it should be joined to the word it modifies, usually without a hyphen.

The really diffuse word above is "usually". :-)

Comment: Both are widely used and acceptable, though it has been noted by renowned nitpickers (RL Graham, for example), that the tendency seems to be shifting in favor dropping the hyphen.

Comment: Good question.  Glancing at the papers of a few authors I trust, it seems to be a wash. e.g., Terry Tao and William Thurston both seem to prefer *non-negative*, while Richard Stanley and John Lee prefer *nonnegative*.  But I don't know if this is even a consistent choice.

Comment: I once had a reviewer who insisted that hyphens are only for compound words like "counter-example" (so that the hyphen links two words that are legitimate words on their own). I had to change all instances of "non-negative" and "non-convex" in my paper to "nonnegative" and "nonconvex."

Comment: Donald Knuth's ["Mathematical Writing" (PDF)](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf) notes (page 4) *"The following words are no longer being hyphenated in current [1987] literature: nonnegative, nonzero"* ... Personally, I'm a big fan of hyphens for adding emphasis, but I'm starting to moderate a bit.

Comment: Came here because of doubt about a method name (`acceptNonnegativeInt` or `acceptNonNegativeInt`).

Comment: Isn't it funny that the IEEE style guide above hyphenates the only word containing the prefix in question: "non-visible"!

Answer (score 22):

[Doug West](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/), who has written [an extensive grammar guide](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/grammar.html) for mathematical writing, had [this](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/grammar.html#non) to say about the subject:

> When a word in English initially has a negation introduced by prefixing "non", the resulting word is hyphenated. The initial sense is the negation, so the hyphen is appropriate. As decades pass and the word is accepted on its own, it becomes a positive concept incorporating the "non". This and familiarity lead to dropping the hyphen. Some of the most familiar examples in mathematics are "nonsingular", "nontrivial", "nonzero", and "nonconstructive". Adding hyphens to these words is now jarring to more readers than is the absence of hyphens. I also use "nonempty", "nonnegative", "nonneighor", and "nonadjacent". However, I would keep the hyphen in "non-word" and "non-edge", for clarity and infrequency.

In particular, "non-negative" might be seen, but "nonnegative" is on the rise enough to be preferred by someone who has clearly given a lot of thought to the grammar of mathematical writing.

---

This conclusion is backed up by the [anecdata](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/anecdata) in the comments:

[Jair Taylor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28545/jair-taylor) [reports](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342643/nonnegative-vs-non-negative#comment6880228_3342643):

> Glancing at the papers of a few authors I trust, it seems to be a wash. e.g., Terry Tao and William Thurston both seem to prefer non-negative, while Richard Stanley and John Lee prefer nonnegative.

[Michael](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/155065/michael) had a reviewer insist on nonnegative.

And [The Count](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/348072/the-count) agrees that "nonnegative" is on the rise.

Answer (score 5):

The [American Mathematical Society Style Guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf) states on page 92, section 12.7.5.3

> Do not hyphenate words formed with the prefixes ... “non-” ...

Similarly, the [Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics Style Manual](https://www.siam.org/Portals/0/Books%20-For%20Authors/SIAM%20Style%20Manual.pdf?ver=2017-11-21-112335-700) states on page 40, section 3.6.6

> Don’t hyphenate  words formed with the prefixes ... "non-" ...

Both guides refer to [The Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch06/toc.html) for exceptions.